# Can't reshape my numpy array for training a KNN model

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray, lbph-algorithm

I try to train a KNN model using a Local Binary Pattern (LBP) descriptor.

My data is a `numpy.array` of shape (67, 26) elements, but `myaray.shape` returns **(67, )**.

I tried to reshape the array like:

```
    myarray.reshape(-1, 26)
```

but it resulted in the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 67 into shape (26)**
```

Thanks you so much

Comment: Can you please provide a small complete example and state the desired output

Comment: what exactly is the type of `myarray`? Perhaps it is an array of type `object` instead of a regular 2D array?

Comment: Are you sure each inner element contains a 1d array with 26 elements?

If you get `(67,)` as your shape, it means it is not 2d array as you expected.

Comment: try `np.stack(myarray)`

Comment: `myarray` is type `object` @MarijnvanVliet

Comment: When i get into numpy array of shape (67,) the elements are another arrays with shape (26,) @MohammadMoridi

Comment: Each LBP descriptor is a 24 length array, and i got 67 LBP descriptors. So i have something like `[array([0, 1, 2, ..., m - 1]),array([0, 1, 2, ..., m - 1]), array([0, 1, 2, ..., m -1]), ... array n -1] `, which is a (67,) shape. To use this dataset for train a KNN model with sklearn a need a array with shape (67, 24). @MichaelSidorov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm not sure I've clearly understood your question, first I'm going to try to mock up your data:

```py
In [101]: import numpy as np

In [102]: myarray = np.empty(shape=67, dtype=object)

In [103]: for i in range(len(myarray)):
     ...:     myarray[i] = np.random.rand(26)
```

Please, run the following code:

```py
In [104]: type(myarray)
Out[104]: numpy.ndarray

In [105]: myarray.shape
Out[105]: (67,)

In [106]: myarray.dtype
Out[106]: dtype('O')

In [107]: type(myarray[0])
Out[107]: numpy.ndarray

In [108]: myarray[0].shape
Out[108]: (26,)
```

If you get the same results as above, [`numpy.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) should do the trick as pointed out by @hpaulj in the comments:

```py
In [109]: x = np.stack(myarray)

In [110]: type(x)
Out[110]: numpy.ndarray

In [111]: x.shape
Out[111]: (67, 26)
```

Comment: Yes!! That's exactly what i need, thanks you very much, and thanks to @hpaulj too. Good luck in your projects!